# How to get proper parameters of SPH simulation?

Tags: algorithms, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, cuda, sph

I'm implementing basic fluid flow simulator using SPH method basing on e.g. https://www10.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/Publications/Theses/2010/Staubach_BA10.pdf.

EDIT (dead url): https://www10.cs.fau.de/publications/theses/2010/Staubach_BT_2010.pdf

So far I've implemented:

- uniform grid constructing
- density and pressure field calculating
- pressure force and viscosity force calculating
- velocity damping force calculating
- surface tension force (surface normal and curvature value) calculating
- acceleration and velocity calculating (basing on these forces and gravity force)

Unfortunately I have a problem with calibrating parameters to avoid particles clustering or spreading them in every possible direction.

Is there a way other than random to calculate proper values of simulation parameters?

My parameters are:

- **particle radius** - (I'd like it to be 0.3 and to set other parameters corresponding to this one)
- **smoothing radius** - 4*particle radius = 1.2
- **particle mass** - decides about everything
- **stiffness** - decides about value of pressure force (k in 2.19 equation)
- **rest density** - decides about pressure field (ρ0 in 2.19 equation)
- **dynamic viscosity** - decides about value of viscosity force (μ in 2.25 equation)
- **gravity force** - (0.0, -9.81, 0.0)
- **velocity damping** - decides about value of damping force (F = -velocity damping * velocity)
- **tension coefficient** - decides about value of surface tension force (σ in 2.30 equation)
- **tension treshold** - minimal length of surface normal to calculate surface tension force (l in 2.31 equation)
- **time step**

I'm pretty sure that my calculations are fine. Unfortunately example values from this or other documents don't work for me and I probably need to calculate them on my own.

I'll be glad to answer any questions about my implementation to help you help me. :)

Oh, almost forgot, I'm using CUDA 6.0.

Comment: Do you mean you have a hard time 1. setting the initial conditions or 2. that the particles tend to gather as time passes ?

Comment: I try to set initial condition for e.g box of 10x10x10 particles. I can't figure out parameters so it acts like water (form some kind of stable droplet and fall down with gravity). Particles explode, pulse like a heart and form clusters or collapse.

Comment: Would you be willing to share your code so we can have a look? Also the link you posted is broken.

Answer (score 1):

A few constraints that usually work in scientific SPH (weakly compressible) computations:

- **particle radius or influence radius, $\Delta$**: define it arbitrarily to set the resolution.
- **smoothing radius, $h$**: it depends on the kernel function, in your case $h=\Delta/4$.
- **rest density $\rho_0$**: 1000 for water.
- **particle mass, $m$**: The number of neighbours in 3D should be about $n=50$. The mass can be calculated as: $m=\frac{4\Delta^3\pi}{3n}\rho_0$
- **Stiffness**: $c<10u_{max}$, where $u_{max}$ is the maximum velocity expected in the simulation.
- **Viscosity $\mu$**: The link is dead, so I don't see the equation but is assume $\mu\approx0.01..0.1$
- **time step**: $dt_{max}\approx0.2\min\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{h}{a_{max}}},\frac{h}{c}\bigg)$
- **initial interparticle distance**: $dx=\sqrt[3]{\frac{4\Delta^3\pi}{3n}}$

Comment: Do you have a reference for these values as recommended values?